# Why this matrix quadratic form is singular?

Tags: matrices

I am reading a paper and I saw:

> $AFF^{H}A^{H}$ is singular, where $A \in \mathbb{C}^{N\times M}$, $F \in \mathbb{}^{M\times1}$ and $N > M$

So I wonder why is that so. My naive guessing is: Since $FF^{H}$ is in $\mathbb{C}^{M\times M}$, $AFF^{H}A^{H}$ will have an $M\times M$ non-singular submatrix, but the rest of them ($N-M$) will be a linear combination of $M$ elements.

However, I am not sure whether my guess is correct or not. Even if my guess is correct, it is not somewhat strictly defined. Could anyone show me a right way?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $XX^H$ and $X^HX$ have the same rank. Then $AFF^HA^H$ has the same rank as 
$$
F^HA^HAF\leq\|A^HA\|\,F^HF,
$$
and $F^HF$ is rank-one.

Answer (score 0):

You may argue in terms of dimensions and rank. The dimension of the image of a product of matrices is never greater than the minimal rank of each factor. In the present case you seem to say (but there is a misprint) that $F$ is of rank 1. So the full product is at most of rank one. In particular, there is at most one non-zero eigenvalue.

Comment: Well then, the statement above is always true regardless of the condition $N>M$?

Comment: Yes, if $N>1$ (and if I understood correctly the def of $F$).